# Can a commit be reverted in Javers?

Tags: javers

I have a scenario where in case a subsequent operation fails, a commit or a shallow delete might need to be reverted. This would be particularly useful in scenarios involving Mongo where there is no atomicity available across collections. Is this possible with Javers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'rollback' option for now. It can be implemented in the future but there could be some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate your method with @Transactional annotation and if an exception occurs the database updates that occurred within that method would rollback which should include the Javers tables.

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/transactional-roll-back.html

Alternatively, you could use Spring AOP to perform a custom rollback and then delete the committed records manually.

[How to call a custom rollback method in Spring Transaction Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684473/how-to-call-a-custom-rollback-method-in-spring-transaction-management)

Hope one of these options helps you.

Comment: `@Transactional` transactions are short-lived, typically just a fraction of second. The author of this question meant reverting e.g. weeks later, after the short-lived transaction is committed

Answer (score 0):

If you need to travel back in time, instead of using Javers, you should redesign your database using functional programming idea called "persistent data structures". At the core of it is that you should never modify any existing data, you should always create new versions of existing entities.

You can read about persistent data structures for example here:

- https://medium.com/@arpitbhayani/copy-on-write-semantics-9538bbeb9f86
- https://medium.com/@mmdGhanbari/persisting-a-persistent-data-structure-3f4cfd46036