# Advice on handling transaction rollbacks with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application that relies on 2 data sources: an third-party HTTP API and a PostgresSQL db. The database is queried using Spring Data JPA, I have set up all the classes for the entities and corresponding repositories.
There is a service with a transactional method that looks something like this:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
 
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @Transactional
    public Entity createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        this.apiService.createEntity(data); // HTTP call
        Entity entity = new Entity(data);
        return this.entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, if any exception were to be thrown during the execution of `createEntity`, the `Entity` object would not be persisted in the database thanks to the `@Transactional` annotation. However, there is nothing preventing or reverting the API call if the entity ends up not being created.

I tried adding a try/catch within `createEntity`, but I noticed that exceptions thrown while committing the transaction would not be catched (ie because of a PostgresSQL error), since they are thrown after the method has actually been executed:

```kotlin
    @Transactional
    public Entity createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        string apiId = this.apiService.createEntity(entity); // HTTP call
        try {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            return this.entityRepository.save(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Not called if exception is thrown while committing transaction
            this.apiService.deleteEntity(apiId);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

If I move the try/catch outside around the call to the method, then I can catch these exception. The problem is that I have no context information for handling the rollback in the third-party API.

```kotlin
try {
    myService.createEntity(data);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // How do I call my API to tell it to rollback whatever has been created?
}
```

I could not find a method to reflect a DB rollback to an external service that matches my use case, any help?

Comment: "However, there is nothing preventing or reverting the API call if the entity ends up not being created" -- Does the API call implement JTA? If yes, then the API will roll back; otherwise the API won't get notified about the rollback and won't do anything.

Comment: @TheImpaler No this is a custom service that makes HTTP calls to an API. I tried looking for some sort of interface I could implement that has callbacks for handling transaction rollbacks but didn't find anything. Do you have any resource that could help me implement JTA on my API service?

Comment: Then SAGA is the way to go. Catching the event and then trying to do a manual "Two-Phase Rollback" is not a great idea. Most likely will fail once in a while randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search on:  saga design pattern

In this case, saga orchestration seems the simplest approach.  Basic idea is to split `MyService` into separate classes, something like

```
// package private 
@Component
class LocalEntityHandler {

    @Transactional
    public Entity createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        return this.entityRepository.save(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// package private 
@Component
class RemoteEntityHandler {

    public String createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        return this.apiService.createEntity(entity);
    }

    public void deleteEntity(String apiId) {
        return this.apiService.createEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

then `MyService` becomes an orchestrator for each step of the process:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final LocalEntityHandler local;
    private final RemoteEntityHandler remote;
   // constructor omitted

    public Entity createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        var apiId = remote.createEntity(data);  // track the context
        try {
            return local.createEntity(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            remote.delete(apiId);  // use the tracked context to clean up
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

and calls the remote API to delete the entity on an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325935/5261392) that seems to work ok using a TransactionalEventListener. Simply publish an event after calling the API service, then catch the event only if the transaction is aborted. Since I can pass whatever data I need to the event, I can easily call my service again to revert the changes:

MyService:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
 
    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @Transactional
    public Entity createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        this.apiService.createEntity(data); // HTTP call
        Entity entity = new Entity(data);
        return this.entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

ApiService:

```java
@Service
public class ApiService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public void createEntity(EntityInputData data) {
        // Do HTTP call
        ApiEvent event = new ApiEvent(/* Whatever data was returned by the API */);
        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
    }

    public void deleteEntity(data) {
        // Do HTTP call
    }
}
```

Then declare a Component for handling events:

```java
@Component
public class ApiEventHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_ROLLBACK)
    void onCreateFailed(ApiEvent event) {
        apiService.deleteEntity(event.data)
    }
}
```

The idea is that the event will only be treated if there is a rollback. Plus I no longer have to deal with a try/catch, everything works as if the method in my ApiService was transactional as well.